# Invalid parameter when using rgrass7 with GRASS 7.2.0. and R 3.3.2

Tags: r, network-analysis, grass

I'm trying to process multiple operations in GRASS 7.2.0 using R 3.3.2 with the `rgrass7` library.

My main goal is to calculate road network distances between multiple locations with GRASS network tools.

My problem is that the locations in my database are organized by individuals and I want to calculate network distances for locations nested in individual, but not for all the locations in the database.

Here's an example of my data structure

```
ID | Locations
--------------
A  |    1
A  |    2
A  |    3
B  |    4
B  |    5
```

I was able to write in GRASS this script that calculates all distances for one ID. I omit the beginning of the script where I load the location (`my_locations`) and the road (`street_vector`) layers and set the region.

```
# Select locations for ID == 'A'
v.extract --overwrite --verbose input=my_locations output=my_locations_sub where="ID='A'"

# Prepare network: connect my_locations to street vector map 
v.net input=street_vectors points=my_locations_sub output=network operation=connect thresh=500

## The option operation=connect allows to create the links between lines and      
## points and to create a single vector map containing lines, nodes and 
## links. 

## The parameter thresh=500 means that only points within the distance of 
## 500 metres are connected to the lines.

# verify result
v.category input=network option=report

# shortest path between all points
v.net.allpairs input=network out=network_dist --overwrite

# output results
v.db.select network_dist
```

Next, I used the `rgrass7` package to execute GRASS7.2.0. command from R 3.3.2.
The objective was to use a `for` loop to generate all my network distance tables with one script.

Here's my code:

```
library(rgrass7)

IDs <- read.table("./path/to/my/ID_list.txt", header = TRUE)

# initialisation of GRASS7
initGRASS(gisBase = "C:/Program Files/GRASS GIS 7.2.0",
          gisDbase = "C:/Users/Me/GRASSdata",
          location = "My_project", mapset = "R", override = TRUE)   

# For loop to calculate road network distance by IDs
for (i in 1: length(IDs)){
  ID <- IDs[i]
  condition <- paste0("ID=\'", as.character(ID), "\'")

  execGRASS('v.extract', parameters = list(input='my_locations', 
             output='my_locations_sub', where=condition))

  execGRASS('v.net', parameters = list(input = street_vectors', 
             points = 'my_locations_sub', output = 'network', 
             operation = 'connect', thresh = 500))

  execGRASS('v.net.allpairs', parameters = list(input='network', 
                                                out='netword_dist'), 
             flags = 'overwrite')

  # Set the path to write files
  path <- paste0("./data/", ID, ".csv")

  # Write file
  execGRASS('db.out.ogr', parameters = list(input = 'network_dist', 
                                            output = path))
```

}

But when I execute `execGRASS` function with `v.net` from GRASS, I got the following error:

```
 Error in doGRASS(cmd, flags = flags, ..., parameters = parameters, 
 echoCmd = echoCmd,  : 
       Invalid parameter name: thresh
```

It's like it doGRASS does not recognize thresh  as a valid `v.net` parameter. I'm a bit stuck here, so if someone has a clue of what I did wrong, that would really help.

Answer (score 0):

I just realize that I made a mistake will copying my code. I missed a ' in `input = 'street_vectors'` in the following section:

```
execGRASS('v.net', parameters = list(input = 'street_vectors', 
         points = 'my_locations_sub', output = 'network', 
         operation = 'connect', thresh = 500))
```